# Brand New HTC Desire C Wi-Fi won't work

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi, htc

Just bought myself a Desire C, pretty decent as far as I've played around with it, but I have a problem with WiFi (this is pretty much the case with all my phones). I can't connect to home network by any means. The network though is totally fine because my pc (from which I type this) is connected, my laptop can connect, my other pc can connect and my old HTC Wildfire (the original one) can connect totally fine. I have searched the web for about 4 hours now to no avail. All I can do is ask here for some solution. I will try to get (in a pirate-like way somehow) the WiFi fixer programs to my phone from my pc but still this is not sure to work, so I expect some help.

Now for the specs of the whole network problem:

**Device:** HTC Desire C (obviously) using Android 4.0.3 (out-of-the-box)

**Router:** Netgear DG834G v5 (if you want to ask anything about config, do so)

**Router protection type:** WPA2 PSK (that's what my phone tells me, I will go with this)

**Notes:**

1. I have an HTC Wildfire that can connect to the very same connection and a couple of Windows 7 machines that can do so as well.
2. I used to have the exact same problem with my previous device (Samsung Galaxy Ace rooted with SanGingerAce) but assumed it was the root config as a friend told me, so did not bother. Said device couls connect totally fine in any other network it has been (including the one of th university I am in), which I will try on my phone tomorrow if that makes any difference).

Comment: What channel (1-11) and protocol (e.g., 802.11b) is your router using?  A lot of devices don't support 802.11n and b/g mixedmode may cause problems.

Comment: Can the phone connect to any other wireless network?

Comment: @ZnewmaN yes it can totally fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved myself:**

I tried after reading a lot of stuff to tweak my router and do a firmware update and I totally messed it up and almost destroyed it. It actually won't work at all and won't be found by wireless or anything, but it was already 5 years old, so I did not mind too much, I went and bought a new one (LogiLink - heard this brand for the first time, but works like a charm). I installed my new router (even though it asked for some things I heard for the first time in my entire life) and it runs on 802.11n perfectly fine for all my 3 computers and all my 3 phones. So turns out my old router was too old apparently.

In conclusion, for anyone reading the question, I believe a firmware update on an old router if done properly (in which I failed horribly) can fix this problem, also as @MatthewRead pointed out in the comments mixed b and g was fairly worse than g only, so you can try this. In any case,